# Applescript, how can I tell chrome window 1 to open link under mouse as tab in chrome window 2?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, applescript, shortcut, browser-tab

I have a a left chrome window and a right chrome window open, I want to open links under the cursor from the left window as tabs in the right window.

I know this should be pretty easily possible, not by me though not knowing applescript.

tell google chrome window 1 etc?

sorry for being vague, nothing I can do but learn applescript or ask.

Comment: my bad, I thought it was more appropriate in stack overflow as it is programming more than it is apple related.

Comment: k I del ask different.